# create database statement not allowed within multi-statement transaction with abp

Tags: aspnetboilerplate

I created a application with "multi page web application" and "Entity Framework", and open it with VS2017, and Update-Package entityframework, change server name for connection string, and F5 to run the application, an exception popups:

[image]

Note: I installed a sql server 2012 express in my local computer. My OS is Win10.
what's wrong?

Comment: You need to [run `Update-Database` command](https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template#introduction).

Comment: Read the getting started document. It says "Open Package Manager Console and run the `Update-Database` command to create your database (ensure that the Default project is selected as .EntityFrameworkCore in the Package Manager Console window)."  See https://aspnetboilerplate.com/Pages/Documents/Zero/Startup-Template-Core#introduction